# Custom routing in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I would like to map the URL `http://localhost:49930/upload` -

RouteConfig.cs-

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new[] { "BrSupervisorTracker.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ExcelUploader",
            url: "upload/{controller}/{action}/{id}",             
            defaults: new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new[] { "BrSupervisorTracker.Controllers" } 
        );
    }
}
```

Controller-

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("ExcelUpload");
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Returns HTTP 404. Any help?

Comment: Order matters- specific routes need to come first. Move the `ExcelUploader` route before the default and change the url to `url: "upload",` (remove the `/{controller}/{action}/{id}`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks. It's working after re-order. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes get evaluated in order so `../upload` matches your first (`Default`) route and attempts to call the `Index()` method of `UploadController` which does not exist, hence the `404` response.

Swap the routes so the `ExcelUploader` routes is before the `Default` route, and also remove the unnecessary segments/parameters

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ExcelUploader",
    url: "upload",
    defaults: new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "Index"},
    namespaces: new[] { "BrSupervisorTracker.Controllers" } 
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    ....
};
```